# How to do a filter nested in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of objects like this:

```
    var lista =
 [
      { nombre: "cartera1", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 1900000.2345 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 898304.45 }
   ]},
      { nombre: "cartera2", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 414612.42 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 1900000.2345 }
   ]},
      { nombre: "cartera3", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 87678.90 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 345409.0345 }
   ]}
];
```

I want to create a new variable and put it into this new variable all the objects where the "saldo" be equal to another variable, like this:

```
var saldosEnLista = lista.filter(x => 
  x.saldos.filter(y => y.saldo == 1900000.2345));
```

This should `return => "cartera1"` and `"cartera2"` but this returns "Cartera1", "cartera2" and "cartera3"
I'm using angular 9 and typeScript
any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is :

```
lista.filter( (cartera) => 
    cartera.saldos.some( (saldo) => 
        saldo.saldo == 1900000.2345));
```

Allow me to elaborate...

`lista` is an array of "**Carteras**" that contains an array of "**Saldos**" so you **`array.prototype.filter`** where it exists within your second array **`array.prototype.some`** **saldo** matching your desired value.

The full example will look like this:

```js
    var lista =
 [
      { nombre: "cartera1", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 1900000.2345 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 898304.45 }
   ]},
      { nombre: "cartera2", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 414612.42 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 1900000.2345 }
   ]},
      { nombre: "cartera3", saldos: [
      { nombre: "saldo1", saldo: 87678.90 },
      { nombre: "saldo2", saldo: 345409.0345 }
   ]}
];

 var result = lista.filter( (cartera) => 
  cartera.saldos.some( (saldo) => 
      saldo.saldo == 1900000.2345));
      
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: oh nice, clever use of .some()

Comment: @AndresGuillenHernandez feel free to mark this as your response if it help you. Thanks